# Sub Matrix of an Orthogonal Matrix is always singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, grassmannian

I am trying to implement Grassmanian rank one update (GROUSE) [as per this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4046.pdf) . For the solution of the least squares problem of **(1)** in the paper the value of $w$ is

$w$ = $(U_{\Omega_{t}}^TU_{\Omega_{t}})^{-1}U_{\Omega_{t}}^Tv_{\Omega_{t}}$

Where $U$ is an $n$ x $d$ ($d$ <$n$) orthogonal matrix and $U_{\Omega_{t}}$ is a sub matrix constructed by selecting the rows from orthogonal matrix $U$ as per the row indices stored in the set $\Omega_{t}$ e.g if $\Omega_{t}$ = $(1,2,4,11,..45,...)$ then the respective rows are stacked to form $U_{\Omega_{t}}$ . But every time I try to calculate $w$ in R Studio it says 
$(U_{\Omega_{t}}^TU_{\Omega_{t}})$ is singular. Note the indices in set $\Omega_{t}$ are randomly generated. So I have no choice of row selection of $U$.
Is a sub matrix of an Orthogonal matrix always singular?

Here is the R code

```
w_t =  (solve(t(U_t_omega) %*% (U_t_omega))) %*% t(U_t_omega) %*% (v_t_omega)
```

Comment: It depends upon what $U$ is? Generically I would say that the product should be non-singular, but if your U has a lot of zeros that might change. I presume that U orthogonal means just that $U^T U$ is the dxd identity matrix?

Comment: yes...$U^TU$  is identity

Comment: But does it contain a lot of zeros or is it more 'random-number' like?

Comment: at start of the algorithm $U$ is generated randomly and then updated as per set of rules..$U$ does not contain that many zeros I guess

Comment: PS: If your matrix only become singular after a couple of steps with your algorithm then it is probably the algorithm which is the culprit, i.e. that it does something to lines which make them more and more linearly dependent. After a while you may run into a submatrix that no longer has full rank? Best thing to do is perhaps to take a small example (say 3 by 2) and then perform your algoritm and print out the matrix after each step

Answer (score 2):

An example: Let $$U = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$

If you select a subset $\Omega\subset \{1,2,3,4\}$ then $\Omega$ has to contain both 1 and 2, or else $U_\Omega$ will have rank less than 2 (and thus your product be singular). For example with $\Omega=\{2,3,4\}$:

$$U_\Omega = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$
And $U_\Omega^T U_\Omega = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0\\  0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$ is singular.

Comment: number of zero entries are much less than the non zero entries ..this is for sure

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be distilled down into the following question:

> Let $S$ be a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors of length $m$. Given some $i\in[n]$, remove the $i_{th}$ coordinate from each $v\in S$ so $\dim(v) = m-1$.
>
> Is $S$ a linearly independent set?

Unfortunately, this question does not have any easy answer. For example, consider the following examples.

### Example

Let $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ such that

$$ v_1 = \left[\begin{matrix}2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \\ 8 \end{matrix}\right]; \quad
v_2 = \left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 5 \\ 7 \end{matrix}\right]; \quad
v_3 = \left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix}\right]. $$

We can check that $S$ is linearly independent. However, consider removing the $i_{th}$ coordinate. Let's check $i=1$ and $i=2$ and see the results.

$i = 1$:

$$ \left\{\left[\begin{matrix} 4 \\ 6 \\ 8 \end{matrix}\right],
\left[\begin{matrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 7 \end{matrix}\right],
\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix}\right]\right\} \text{is not linearly independent.}$$

$i = 2$:

$$ \left\{\left[\begin{matrix} 2 \\ 6 \\ 8 \end{matrix}\right],
\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 5 \\ 7 \end{matrix}\right],
\left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix}\right]\right\} \text{is linearly independent.}$$

This informs us that it is the choice of position we remove that decides whether or not these sets are linearly independent, which is based upon the entries of the vectors (the columns of $U$, in your case).

### The Paper

To achieve nonsingularity, I have a few suggestions based on what little I could personally take away from the paper.

- If $U$ is arbitrary, I would suggest always using the standard basis
  vectors $e_i$ for your columns, as @H. H. Rugh did in their example.
- If the only restriction on $S$ is that $\dim(S) = d <
     n$, then perhaps consider choosing which $d$ basis vectors to use so
  that $\Omega_t$ has a smaller chance of removing important rows (i.e.
  rows with a 1 in them).